# root element must be well-formed-android manifest

Tags: android, eclipse, android-manifest

**my manifest file  the error is listed below i think it has something to do with the repeated manifest side by side i can't fix it **

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.BinaryRelics"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Homescreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Arcademode"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_arcademode" >
    </activity>
    </application>
```

**The error is on this line below notice how the 2 manifest tags are next to each other if i delete the first one it says that the application must be a direct child of the manifest if i delete the 2nd one it moves the error to the next line of code**

```
    </manifest><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <application>
    <activity
        android:name="com.BinaryRelics.Arcademode"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_arcademode"
        android:parentActivityName="com.BinaryRelics.Homescreen" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.BinaryRelics.Homescreen" />
    </activity>
    </application>

    </manifest>>>>>>>> Added
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you have two manifests and two applications defined? You may get away with two applications (I've never tried) but you can have **only one root node** and it must be 'manifest'

Delete the entire line in the middle

```
</manifest><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
```

From the second defined `application` node take the `<activity ...> ... </activity>` out and move it inside the the first defined `application`.

Then delete the left over `<application></application>` from the end.